# Compare array with Json

Tags: python, json

Is there any better way to do this?

```
import json

product_data = [x for x in open('product_strings.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().split(',')]
json_data = json.load(open('tedata.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))


for product_no in json_data:
    for product in product_data:
        if product.lower() in json_data[product_no]['name'].lower():
            print (product.lower(), json_data[product_no]['name'])
        elif product.lower() in json_data[product_no]['des'].lower():
            print (product.lower(), json_data[product_no]['name'])
```

tedata.json contains (6mb with ~1000 objects)

```
{
    "12345": {
        "owner": "BMW int",
        "doman": "20/01/2016",
        "des": "a beautiful BMW with improvements with respect to older version of bmw.",
        "dopur": "25/07/2016",
        "purchaser": "Mitsubishi, Japan",
        "name": "BMW-8"
    },
    "12346": {
        "owner": "audi",
        "doman": "20/01/2016",
        "des": "a beautiful skoda with improvements with respect to older version of skoda.",
        "dopur": "25/07/2016",
        "purchaser": "Mokoto, Japan",
        "name": "skoda-1"
    }
}
```

product_strings file contains (small with ~100 such string)

```
audi,bmw,jaguar
```

code for testing:

```
import json

tedata = """{
    "12345": {
        "owner": "BMW int",
        "doman": "20/01/2016",
        "des": "a beautiful BMW with improvements with respect to older version of bmw.",
        "dopur": "25/07/2016",
        "purchaser": "Mitsubishi, Japan",
        "name": "BMW-8"
    },
    "12346": {
        "owner": "audi",
        "doman": "20/01/2016",
        "des": "a beautiful skoda with improvements with respect to older version of skoda.",
        "dopur": "25/07/2016",
        "purchaser": "Mokoto, Japan",
        "name": "skoda-1"
    }
}"""

product_strings = "audi,bmw,jaguar"

product_data = [x for x in product_strings.split(',')]
json_data = json.loads(tedata)


for product_no in json_data:
    for product in product_data:
        if product.lower() in json_data[product_no]['name'].lower():
            print (product.lower(), json_data[product_no]['name'])
        elif product.lower() in json_data[product_no]['des'].lower():
            print (product.lower(), json_data[product_no]['name'])

##prints ===>bmw BMW-8
```

Comment: Who or what are `ttl` and `abst`? Is this code even having the desired functionality with those results of the `if`/`elif`?

Comment: Mistakes in converting working code to snippet. Idea is to check if the name is in the object name or description. Please see my working code.

Answer (score 4):

Your identifiers could be altered to make things clearer. What you're calling `product_data` is just a list of *names*, so perhaps `product_names` would be better. Then it follows that `product` should become `product_name`, as `for product_name in product_names:` makes perfect sense. And you should only call things `x` where that's the convention of the domain (e.g. mathematics).

---

One obvious code simplification is that you can iterate over a dictionary's keys and values simultaneously:

```
for product_no, product in json_data.items():
    for product_name in product_names:
        ...
```

This way your comparisons lower down are neater:

```
if product_name.lower() in product['name'].lower():
```

---

Rather than `product_name.lower()` every time you compare to it, lowercase everything once:

```
product_names = [name for name in product_strings.lower().split(',')]
                                               # ^ e.g. here
```

In this case you don't need it at all, as `product_strings` is *already* lowercase!

---

You can do multiple comparisons in one (logical) line, too, reducing duplication:

```
if (product_name in product['name'].lower() 
        or product_name in product['des'].lower()):
    print (product, product_spec['name'])
```

Comment: Looks nicer now.

Comment: for product_no, product in json_data.items(): will not work. I need to loop for data in product_data: not in json_data:

Comment: @Rahul ...so? You can still loop over `product_data` (now `product_names`) within that loop, just as you currently do inside `for product_no in json_data:`. It will work just fine; you loop over both.

Comment: product_names and json_data are not same dict/array. you mean `for product in product_data, product_no in json_data:`?

Comment: @Rahul what? I know they're different, but your code iterates over both of them. You're welcome to try what you think I mean, but it won't work. So try **what I actually wrote** instead. I will update to show how it relates to the other line; note that I have renamed things per the opening paragraph.

Comment: Oh! I thought the other way in absence of second line. This is bright idea to decrease the code. Got it.